# Adding dates through variable PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a question regarding the sum of dates through PHP code.
I had the code below running smoothly until about two weeks ago, but I believe because the version of PHP should have been updated it stopped working. The code is as follows:

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 'wpo_wcpdf_due_date', 10, 2 );

function wpo_wcpdf_due_date ($template_type, $order) {
    if ($template_type == 'packing-slip') { // put due date only on packing-slip

        $max_days = 0;

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
            if($cart_item['days_manufacture'] > $max_days)
                $max_days = $cart_item['days_manufacture'];

        $days_manufacture = $max_days;
        $invoice_date = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_wcpdf_invoice_date', true );
        $due_date = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $invoice_date . " + $days_manufacture weekdays") );
        ?>
        <tr class="due-date">
            <th>Término da Confecção:</th>
            <td><?php echo $due_date;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

This code basically amounted to the date of a request made in the application of woocommerce ($ invoice_date) with other data generated by the cart products (`$ days_manufacture`) however this variable has to be in weekdays.

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the part of the code that was in trouble follows:

```html
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
            if($cart_item['days_manufacture'] > $max_days)
                $max_days = $cart_item['days_manufacture'];
```

I replaced by:

```html
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
     if(get_post_meta($item['product_id'], 'days_manufacture', true) > $max_days )
      $max_days = get_post_meta($item['product_id'], 'days_manufacture', true);
```

Thank you all!